# Framer motion stagger parameter type error

Tags: typescript, framer-motion

I am using Typescript in my project and i am using framer motion package for render some cards. When I am using stagger it gives me an error

Error

**Identifier expected.ts
Parameter '(Missing)' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

Here is my code

```
    <motion.div
      key={index}
      initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 200 }}
      whileInView={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.01, stagger(0.1) }}
      className="relative transition ease-in-out hover:scale-105"
    >
      <Image src={item.image} alt="card1" width={250} height={250} />
      <div className="absolute border-2 border-zinc-500 hover:border-[#20E3A1] flex flex-col justify-end w-full hover:backdrop-brightness-50 rounded-2xl h-full cursor-pointer bottom-0 p-2">
        <div className="bg-gray-950 bg-opacity-50 rounded-2xl">
          <h3 className="text-slate-50 h-fit  p-1">{item.title}</h3>
          <h4 className="text-slate-50 text-sm  p-1">
            {item.subTitle}
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
```

Help me to fix this issue.